# Change Windows Terminal font programmatically

Tags: winapi, fonts, console-application, windows-terminal

I want to write a 2D chess program.
It does not require much user input so it will use only the Windows Console, not any GUI.
I know how to access the Windows Console API and change its font using Assembly language or C++.
Using the same method for Windows Terminal does not work as it is written to behave as font agnostic terminal.
However, in Windows Terminal you can set the font to your liking through the settings.
I want to change the Windows Terminal font from the outside, before or during when Windows Terminal launches.
I know all Windows Terminal settings are stored in a JSON file so I can manipulate it before lanching.
I'm looking for a more straight forward approach like a command line option or a WINAPI call.
I could not find any.
Is there any way to programmaticaly change the Windows Terminal font?

Comment: Bit-of-topic, but in general I would kinda strongly advise against changing fonts etc for a terminal application. One really lovely thing about a CLI / TUI is that the user can decide terminal / font / colors /size for himself. IMO an application shouldn't rely on the use of a specific font apart from certain properties e.g. support of unicode.

Comment: Having said that, I don't think there is any API call to do such a thing. You will have to edit the JSON yourself. Don't forget to reset the font on exit, however this might be impossible, if someone simply kills the program :D

Comment: That is exactly my problem. The default Windows Terminal font does not have the Unicode chess characters. Only the MS Gothic, MS Pgothic and MS UI Gothic have good chess pieces. Other fonts have a bug that shows the black pawn larger than other pieces.

Comment: A 2D chess program should be a GUI program. After all, i'ts easier to draw manually with Direct2D than to mess with the terminal.

Comment: It is a chess engine so interactivity with the user will be minimal.

Comment: @DannyCohen maybe a suggestion to the user what font to set his terminal to is good enough

Comment: @leun4m That would be my last resort if no one have a solution.

Comment: You're already trying to enforce a (bad IMO) non-standard terminal app so enforcing a font doesn't make any difference. What if the user doesn't have the font installed BTW? Even the standard fonts can be removed or differ per system. A good TUI framework should let you build a well-formatted app regardless of the font used.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex)

> Sets extended information about the current console font.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly for console. It does not work at all for Windows Terminal. It gives no error either...